# Evaluating absolute inequalities

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have the *expression
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}}$$

and I am being asked to evaluate the case when $2|a| \geq|b|$

Logically I know what this statement mean but don't know how it applies to this problem: Cases when $a$ is twice greater than the distance of $b$ is from $0$.
(Correct me if i'm wrong)

I also know that absolute values on both sides of an equation are inpracticle and it would be better to write the inequality as $|a/b| \geq 1/2$.

Which can also be written as $a/b \geq  1/2$ or $a/b \leq 1/2$ which doesn't make any sense.

here's a link to the problem (#3)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdBbK.jpg

Thank you, I would appreciate help I've been struggling with this for a while

Comment: That first line is not an equation.  What equals what?

Comment: My problem dosent set it up as an equation

Comment: In that case, it's an *expression*.

Comment: Then why do you call it an equation?  Do you just mean that you want to understand the function $F(a,b)=\frac 1{\sqrt {4a^2-b^2}}$ ? what do you want to know about that function?

Comment: I guess it is not a function but an expression

Comment: $|a/b|\ge 1/2$ iff $a/b\ge 1/2$ or $a/b\le -1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\frac{\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}}{-(4a^2-b^2)}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^2-b^2}}$$
and here we have $$2|a|>|b|$$

Answer (score 0):

The only reason they say $2|a| \geq|b|$ is that if $2|a| \not\geq|b|$, the square root $\sqrt{4a^2 - b^2}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: because it would make it negative?

Comment: @OlivierPerrault Yes, it would make the expression inside the square root negative.

Comment: Is there a full proof way to come up with conditions to make sure that the root is not negative like this?

Comment: Sure. $$4a^2-b^2\geq0\\4a^2\geq b^2\\2|a|\geq|b|$$